# Save previous answer of Chatbot

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a QnA Bot build with `Azure Bot framework` in C#.
I want to save the previous answer of my Chatbot to check if my bot repeated the same answer. If yes, it should send an extra message (asking if human interaction is needed).

I know how to send the extra message, and I know it should be possible with ConversationState / user state. I am using Dialogs too, that's why all the samples I found online couldn't help me ( They don't use dialogs, so the implementation is different).

I just don't understand how to save something in ConversationState and how to access it afterward.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've had a look at the docs, such as [Save user and conversation data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)? If so, just remember there are a few prerequisites:

1. You need to specify a location to save the actual state. In the link it's using memory (`var storage = new MemoryStorage();`), but you might want to store to disk/database/blob storage/whatever
2. The Bot takes in the conversation and user state objects in it's constructor:

   private BotState _conversationState;
   private BotState _userState;

   public StateManagementBot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState)
   {
       _conversationState = conversationState;
       _userState = userState;
   }
3. Once that's done, the code later one tries to (a) retrieve an object from state, *if it exists*. If it doesn't exist, it will get created there and then.

   var conversationStateAccessors =  _conversationState.CreateProperty(nameof(ConversationData));

   var conversationData = await conversationStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new ConversationData());

So, of relevance here are the "ConversationData" object, which is whatever kind of custom object you want. Perhaps a List or whatever makes sense for you. Next is the "`() => new ConversationData()`" portion, which is basically an inline function to just create a new instance of the the object. You'd create, say, a new List. Subsequent calls to "`var conversationData =...`" anywhere in your bot (e.g. inside OnMessageActivityAsync) would return the (now-existing) instance of List, which you can check the history of.

Just be aware this could grow quite large, so it might be worth cleaning out of time (e.g. only store the last 20 or something), if you're having long, ongoing conversations with users - this would depend on your scenario of where / how you use your bots, I'd think.

Comment: can I have multiple / different propterys? because of the dialogs I am using, the code already creates an property 

"    await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);    "

with dialogState.

Comment: I think I tested that once and had trouble, but can't recall 100%. The alternative is to create your own higher level class that you use instead, that contains "DialogState" as a property, and your list<string> as a property, and anything else. In that case, the entire complex object will get saved as is to whatever storage you choose.

Comment: Mhh okay. Thank you, i am going to try that.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What part is giving trouble?

Comment: I dont understand how to put DialogState into a higher level class, because I don't understand how dialogState is built and used. I didnt create any of this "state"-stuff-code, that is generated by botframework